# https connection between 2 java servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, https, ssl-certificate

Good day.

I should want to run a Tomcat Java servlet, present in a domain, from another Tomcat Java servlet, which is located in a different domain.
All in https.
For the connection use the class HttpsURLConnection.
When I run:
"OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(hpcon.getOutputStream());"
gives me the following exception:
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.yet.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.yet.the supplier of services.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
The SSL certificate is Let's Encript and is installed on web server.
How can I solve the problem?

Best regards and good work.

Stefano Errani

Comment: This is an ugly problem, and I am facing something similar right now actually.  The bottom line is that if the SSL cert is from a known provider, then `HttpsURLConnection` should just work, without you having to intervene.  Do some research and check if Let's Encrypt is a supported provider for Tomcat/Java.  One other sanity check would be to try to hit the other Tomcat from a web browser.  Do you get a warning, or does the page just open?

Comment: The certificate was proposed and installed to me from the provider where there are the domains, and then Tomcat/Java.
If I run the servlet with browser (in https) I haven't problem.

Comment: Scary.  Then maybe this provider isn't recognized by Java but it is by the browser.  You might have to go with a more widely recognized provider.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you saying that I must try another certificate?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if the browser recognizes it, then the cert doesn't have a chain of authority problem most likely.  Then, it is strange that Java does not recognize it, leading me to think that maybe the provider is known to the browser, but not to Java.

Comment: The fact that the certificate is installed on the web server can cause problems?
Also consider that I do the redirect automatically from the url from the ad http to https for the pages in Tomcat I have placed this code:
"the<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Secured</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>"
and it works.

Comment: I have an update about it.
I tried to run the same servlet from the test server that I have in my pc (which is obviously not the certificate) and is in localhost.
It worked.
At this point I think that the problem is on Tomcat or on the domain that runs the servlet.